# Determine if a row of strings exists in multiple rows of string

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have a list of songs. Each song has a list of names of all the people needed to perform that song.

E.g.

```
Song1 | Jess | Julia | Mandy | Fred | Simon | 
Song2 | Jess | Julia |       | Fred | Simon |
Song3 |      | Julia |       | Fred | Simon |
```

I then have a list of people that are present.

E.g

```
Jess | Julia | Fred | Simon
```

I want to compare the list of people that are present against the list of songs so we know which songs can be performed.

If we are comparing the two examples we know that Song2 and Song3 can be performed but not Song1.
Song2 because Jess, Julia, Fred, and Simon are present. Song3 because Julia, Fred, Simon are present (Jess is there but not needed).
Song1 shouldn't be returned since Mandy is not present.

I would like the song titles that will be in the first column returned.

So far I have something like this but I know its not right:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:1, B2:E2), A2, "Nope")
```

Where A1:1 is the row with the people present and B2:E2 is the people needed to perform the song. A2 is the title of the song.

I originally tried:

```
=IF(A1:1=B2:E2, A2, "Nope")
```

But knew that wouldn't work since it is comparing for exact matchings.

Thank you.

Edit:

If I were to write this as code it would probably be something like this.

```
const presentSingers = ['Julia', 'Mandy', 'Jess', 'Fred']
const song1 = ['Julia', 'Mandy']
const song2 = ['Julia', 'Mandy', 'Jess', 'Fred']
const song3 = ['Julia', 'Rachel', 'Mandy']
const allSongs = [song1, song2, song3]

const songsThatCanBePerformed = []

allSongs.forEach((song) => {
   let present = true
   song.forEach((singer) => {
      if (!singers.includes(singer)) {
         present = false
      }
   })
   if (present) {
      songsThatCanBePerformed.push(song)
   }
})

console.log(songsThatCanBePerformed)
```

Comment: Is there only ever a few singers (as presented in examples) or does the list of possible singers get quite long? And if yes, now lobg?

Comment: The list of present performers will be somewhere between 10 and 16 different names.

Each song will have 10 to 16 different performers.

Comment: Is a vb solution viable (in spite of your google sheet tag)?

Comment: Thank you for your response. It actually helped jog my memory that Google Sheets supports scripts too. I was able to solve my problem with that.

Comment: Hmmm... ok. At the time I was still considering how fancy and adaptable the solution 'might' need to be. But I've since worked out this can be done in a formula that's actually quiet adaptable to possible changes in the data structure (see further below).

Answer (score 1):

You could use this formula

```
=if(average(countif(F4:J4,vlookup(F4,N4:N7,1,false)),countif(F4:J4,vlookup(G4,N4:N7,1,false)),countif(F4:J4,vlookup(H4,N4:N7,1,false)),countif(F4:J4,vlookup(I4,N4:N7,1,false)),countif(F4:J4,vlookup(J4,N4:N7,1,false)))<1,"Cannot Perform","Can Perform")
```

where

F4:J4 = represents the performers required

H4:N7 = represents the attendance of the performers

in short , this formula works by returning 1 if the performers are present and getting the average of the attendance, everyone is present the average would be 1 and if not it would be less than 1.

if you do not want a complete match then you can use wildcharacters in your vlookup search.

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets supports a scripting language that allows you to write "JavaScript-like" code.

[More can be found about Google App Script here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)

Get the members from the sheet like this.

```
const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// Get the members sheet
const membersSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(membersSheetTitle);
const membersData = membersSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
```

The songs can be retrieved in a similar fashion.

Now, perform your calculations like this.

```
  const songsThatCanBePerformed = [];
  allSongs.forEach((song) => {
    let present = true;  
    for (let i = 1; i <= song.length; i++) {
      const singer = song[i];
      if (singer && !presentSingers.includes(singer)) {
        present = false;
      }
    }

    // Add just the song title to the list.
    if (present && song[songTitleIndex]) {
      songsThatCanBePerformed.push([song[songTitleIndex]]);
    }
  });

  if (songsThatCanBePerformed.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
```

The results can be entered into the sheet using the following.

```
  // Set where the data should be written
  const startRow = 2;
  const startCol = 7;
  const numRows = songsThatCanBePerformed.length;
  const numCols = 1;
  const range = membersSheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, numRows, numCols);
  range.clearContent();
  // write the results
  range.setValues(songsThatCanBePerformed);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you could try:

[image]

Formula in `H1`:

```
=FILTER(A1:A3,MMULT(ISNA(MATCH(B1:F3,J1:M1,0))*(B1:F3<>""),SEQUENCE(5,1,1,0))=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here something that's quite simple, yet adaptable, (and the simplest I could come up with so far that fully addresses the described functionality):

```
Using B2 as helper cell to concatenate the "artists present" list 
{=IF(SUM(IF(B5:H5<>"",IF(ISERROR(FIND(B5:H5,$B$2)),0,1)))=COUNTA(B5:H5),"Yes","Nope")}
```

Note the {}: This is an array formula.

Pictogram:
[image: Demo of working sheet]

Additional info:
The above is fairly dynamic in that it supports entry of artist names being non-contiguous (in both the list of those present, and the list beside each song). i.e. it'll still work even if there's empty cells between artist names.

It also allows for (e.g.) to have artist names in two or more rows instead of 1. In case (e.g.) you'd prefer a narrower viewing window.

And it works just as well if you decide to have artist names in columns instead of rows, for either the 'Those Present' list or the Songs-Artist lists or both.

Using Delimiters:
To add another level of integrity, you could include delimiters in the concatenation of Artists Present (in case of an oddity such as 'Simon**e**' + 'Mal' matching Ema).

Comment: For reference: I have confirmed the above works in Google sheets

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=AND(NOT(ISNA(HLOOKUP(B2:INDEX(B2:F2,COUNTA(B2:F2)),$A$7:$D$7,1,FALSE))))
```

- Formula will return an array of either the singer name or `#N/A` depending on finding the name in the song requirement
- `B2:INDEX(B2:F2,COUNTA(B2:F2))` ensures that we do not include the blanks in our data.

  - Assumes names are listed sequentially from left-to-right with no intervening empty cells.
  - If that is not the case, a more complex formula can be devised.
- `NOT(ISNA(...` changes that to an array of booleans
- `AND` ensures that every element in the array is `TRUE` for Can Perform to test `TRUE`

***Note: In early versions of Excel, and in Google Sheets, this must be entered as an array formula; either with `ctrl+shift+enter` in Excel or, in Sheets as `=ArrayFormula(...`***

[image]

***If Artist names are non-contiguous***

```
=AND(NOT(ISNA(HLOOKUP(FILTER(B2:F2,B2:F2<>""),$A$7:$D$7,1,FALSE))))
```

can be used in Office 365 and Google Sheets (with `ArrayFormula(...`. Earlier versions of Excel do not have the `FILTER` function, however.

Comment: Erm... that's not working. And you can tell by looking at your own results.

Comment: @Spinner You are correct, I had the logic backwards.  Will edit. Tks

Comment: Erm... based on your image, it seems like you changed the result there, but the actual formula above still doesn't work.

Comment: @Spinner It works fine here.  And I edited the screenshot to also show the formula as entered.  What kind of result are you getting?

Comment: Huh. Turns out, it almost works if entered as a dynamic array (i.e. not using Ctrl, Shift, Enter). But doesn't work as a 'legacy' array formula. That aside it still doesn't always work, as it doesn't cater for gaps in the singer's names. i.e. It will produce a FALSE even if all singers are present, but the names for a given songs aren't in contiguous cells, left-to-right. You might note in the author's examples, it may be the case that names are non-contiguous. This is one of the features I focused on getting right. And is addressed by the formula I suggest in my answer. :)

Comment: More testing: Doesn't work at all in Google sheets (which of course doesn't support dynamic array)

Comment: Suggest editing the bit about 'early versions of excel and google sheets to say 'not supported by either'.

Comment: @Spinner I can't test on earlier versions of Excel. But you are clearly wrong about it not working in Sheets, so I suspect you are also not applying it correctly in the early version of Excel.

Comment: Ok. I tested in Google sheets and (as mentioned) didn't work in my tests. Also tested in both current and 2010 versions of excel. And (as covered) only works in current version and only if entered as a dynamic array. I'll leave it up to you to do any further testing and/or qualification of your post.

Comment: @Spinner If you care to share your test in Sheets, I'll take a look to see what your issue is. As mentioned, the original works without a problem (on contiguous names) here.

Comment: Separately though (as already covered), you seem to be overlooking (what I consider is) a fairly basic point: Your formula doesn't cater for non-contiguous artist names. Maybe you think that doesn't matter. But it does impose unnecessary strictures on the user. So why would you do that?

Comment: Hmmm... seems we were typing at the same time. As already covered, I'm kinda done here. I've spent more than enough time creating and testing something that works and addresses all of the stated requirements. Sorry to say (and not being mean in any way) but further work on something that doesn't, seems inefficient.